# Angular JS factory function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want the use set method of factory but both of return default how can I fix that problem?

```
app.factory("DualListShareFactory", function(){

    var selectedArray=[];
    return{
        getSelectedArray: function () {

            return selectedArray;
        },

        setSelectedArray: function (array){

            selectedArray=array;
        }
    }
});
```

Using ng-dual List from https://github.com/tushariscoolster/ng-duallist

I'm tkining it not working:     DualListShareFactory.setSelectedArray(vm.rightValue);
I use other method  for and push but I am received same error .

```
app.controller("duallist2", function($scope,DualListShareFactory){
    var vm=this;
    vm.property='duallist2';
    activate();

    function activate() {
        vm.leftValue = [];
        vm.rightValue = [];
        vm.addValue = [];
        vm.removeValue = [];

        function loadMoreLeft() {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.incomingItem.length; i++) {
                vm.leftValue.push({
                    'name': $scope.incomingItem[i]
                });

            }
        };

        function loadMoreRight() {
        }


        vm.options = {
            leftContainerScrollEnd: function () {
            },
            rightContainerScrollEnd: function () {
            },
            leftContainerSearch: function (text) {
                console.log(text)
                vm.leftValue = $filter('filter')(leftValue, {
                    'name': text
                })

            },
            rightContainerSearch: function (text) {

                vm.rightValue = $filter('filter')(rightValue, {
                    'name': text
                })
            },
            leftContainerLabel: 'Gelen Parçalar',
            rightContainerLabel: 'Seçilen Parçalar',
            onMoveRight: function () {
                console.log('right');
                console.log(vm.addValue);

            },
            onMoveLeft: function () {
                console.log('left');
                console.log(vm.removeValue);
            }

        };
        loadMoreLeft();

        var leftValue = angular.copy(vm.leftValue);

        var rightValue = angular.copy(vm.rightValue);

    }   console.log(vm.rightValue);
        DualListShareFactory.setSelectedArray(vm.rightValue);
    });
```

Comment: I fixed problem you can find code block in main question part

Comment: believe me i tried ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not this will work but try "this",

```
app.factory("DualListShareFactory", function(){

    this.selectedArray=[];

    return{
        getSelectedArray: function () {
            return this.selectedArray;
        },

        setSelectedArray: function (array){
            this.selectedArray = array;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("testapp", ["ng-duallist"]);
app.factory("DualListShareFactory", function(){
    var selectedArray = [];

    return{
        getSelectedArray: function () {
            return selectedArray
        },

        setSelectedArray: function (array){
            angular.copy(array, selectedArray);
        }
    }
});
```

using for this add the other code block before ending function.

```
    onMoveRight: function () {
        DualListShareFactory.setSelectedArray(vm.rightValue);
    },
    onMoveLeft: function () {
        DualListShareFactory.setSelectedArray(vm.rightValue);
    }

};
loadMoreLeft();


var leftValue = angular.copy(vm.leftValue);

var rightValue = angular.copy(vm.rightValue);
```

Comment: ım using right value and it crated in function. because of that ı m not using  this value out side of funciton. I have to equal factory function's variable to rgiht value inside in a function